# How can I make one python file run another modal?

Tags: python

I am new to Python – I used VB6 years ago to write small systems for personal use which involved multiple screens and being able to pass data around. I would like to do this in Python and have looked about for examples.  These examples allow a screen (MainFrame01.py) with a button event to call a (test01.py).

```
import os 
os.system('python test01.py')
**********************************************
from subprocess import Popen
Popen('python test01.py')
**********************************************
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "test01.py"])
```

My question is how do I make this called python code Modal and how can I return any data back?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if you want to combine multiple Python scripts, you use them as modules.

Script A can import script B as a module and call methods from that module.

With the construct

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_stuff()
```

you can define code that is only executed when the script is called directly, but not when it is imported by another script. This way, you can write Python scripts that act both as modules and standalone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My idea is to have say progA with a number of button selection events B, C etc these would open screens B, C etc. Screen B would have multiple selection processing that would then access MySQL tables with the selected data requirements. Screen C would open to enable maintenance of MySQL tables etc. This is why i am asking about opening screens in a modal state and being able to return data. Is this not possible in Python or should i be looking at some other language?

Comment: This is totally possible with Python and I suggest you use pyqt for it.

Comment: I am already using wxFormBuilder as this seemed to be suggested as a good GUI development tool. My question still is what would this code look like. I mean could you show me an example of python code that calls in a modal state and how it would return result data

Comment: WxWidgets sucks. I can strongly recommend against using this outdated technology. I feel your question is too broad to answer it here. Why don't you start putting your GUI in place and then ask about the details like modality.

Answer (score 0):

Probably do this.

```
import os
os.system("put your file name in here.py")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).